# Adding polygon over imported TIFF using Google Earth Pro

Tags: geotiff-tiff, google-earth

Google Earth Pro lets me add a polygon just fine when I just have the base image on but when I select an imported TIFF and try to outline a feature with the polygon tool, it only places dots on the screen, it doesn't show the area being bounded.  I double checked the shading to make sure its visible.

How do I do this?